# Widget cant send signal if it is disabled

Tags: c++, qt

I have a basic question

There is a pushbutton to enable a widget as follows:

```
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnOne, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentOne, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
```

and this widget is connected to a slot to adjust a value:

```
 connect(ui->widget_currentOne, &CurrentButtonOne::getValue, this, &stageProgram::setCurrOnChannelOne);
```

and the slot is:

```
void stageProgram::setCurrOnChannelOne(unsigned int current_uA)
{
    tetra_grip_api::stimulation_set_current( m_channelOne, current_uA); // second argument I get as signal from the widget
}
```

But what I now need if the widget is **disabled** the signal value should be `0` (meaning the `current_uA = 0`)

I was thinking to call different slot and set `current_uA = 0`. Looks like it's not possible..

I tried using *Lambda*

```
connect(ui->widget_currentOne, &CurrentButtonOne::getValue,
        [this](unsigned int current_uA) { setCurrOnChannelOne(ui->widget_currentOne->isEnabled() ? current_uA : 0); } ); 
//this does not send 0 when it is disabled
```

can you suggest a way to send zero signal when the widget is disabled ?

Comment: Do your lambda work? Does it get called at all? How does it fail? Is `CurrentButtonOne::getValue` a `signal`? It seems like a getter, not a signal of an event.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to define the following slot for the `CurrentButtonOne`:

```
void disableMe() {

    //Disable
    setDisabled(true);

    //Reset current_uA
    current_uA = 0;
}
```

and then connect the signals and slots as follows:

```
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnOne, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentOne, &CurrentButtonOne::disableMe);
```

Hope this helps.